# XSLT dependencies across OSGI Bundles

Tags: xslt, osgi

I have been researching OSGI to determine its viability for updating an existing project.  The project currently consists of modules (which are basically just directories) that contain XSL Transforms.  The transforms contain dependencies on transforms from other modules in the form of xsl:import and xsl:include statements. The reason I am considering OSGI is because as the number of modules increase, it is becoming more difficult to keep track of the dependencies and effectively test the modules.

Is it possible using the OSGI framework to declare XML/XSLT resources contained in a bundle and reference these resources in the import statements of XSL Transforms in a separate bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this works as Lukasz indicated, you need to write a simple URIResolver based on the extender model. An interesting approach is to use the Provide-Capability and Require-Capability headers to model the dependencies. This will allow you to handle the dependencies with good diagnostics, allows you run multiple versions side-by-side, and it will work with OBR, a resolver that can find the missing parts. See http://www.osgi.org/blog/2012/03/requirements-and-capabilities.html

And this would be the first time I see use of the fact that XSLT is XML ... you could write a simple style sheet that generated the Require-Capability headers! :-)

Comment: Is this already available? I can't find any information on when R5 comes, or if it is already there?

Comment: R5 final draft will be shown on OSGi DevCon BOF (EclipseCon) Tuesday night. Anyway, the described model already works with 4.3 frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems very interesting. Personally, I am working on a system that has two bundles. One bundle contains XSLT Processor implementation (we are using Saxon) while the second one contains multiple XSLT files (which make usage of `xsl:import` instruction). And it works cool in OSGi environment (Fuse ESB actually) however we needed to implement `javax.xml.transform.URIResolver` interface and pass it to converter.

I suppose you would need to use the similar approach. Hope this helps.

Comment: Lukasz, this sounds like a good approach.  Do you have any code examples or links to how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use Maven for dependency management if I were you - it's simpler to set up your dependencies and it handles transitive dependencies very well indeed. Use OSGi if you need to be able to change the XSL modules at *run-time*. In both cases you'll need to implement the  `URIResolver` mentioned in the other answer.